# I can't use Cocoapods to update Podfile

Tags: cocoapods

I wanted to open app(UAAppReviewManagerExample),but this demo uses CocoaPods, so I wanted to update Podfile, but it failed. It asks me to find my another app's xcodeproj file in my Mac. What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening wrong file, You have to open xcodeworkspace and not xcodeproj.
Also check whether instead of deleting files from project, have you deleted the files of dependency from pods. Because according to image you sent, Xcode is unable to find the files on your system, but it is getting an update request from podfile.